# Debugging/ coding C# on smartphones

Tags: c#, android, debugging, editor, nokia

I recently learnt c#. I travel alot and cant take my laptop with me everywhere, 
so i was wondering if there was a phone i could code c# in and debug it on the phone itself and edit e.t.c
i dont want to code FOR the phone. 
i want to code IN the phone.
its not even necessary to compile and get an exe on the phone. Even if i can just code it and then debug it and save the resulting code in txt file would be great.
so is there any phone on which i can do that
and i would prefer , Phones with linux based os or androids.
Is there any way to Debug c# code on these phones.
thanks alot guys

Comment: Use an RDP or VNC solution like PocketCloud to remote a desktop session to your phone. If you want to actually write it on your phone, there are various text editors  on the android market for any given android phone. Scripting Layer for Android is a good set of scripting languages for the android, but wont write C#. That said, this is really a hardware question, not software, so it's off topic.

Comment: i want to write on the phone not start a session from a pc to my phone.
Is there any software that can help me edit c# code on a specific phone is what im asking

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably a web based C# editor / compiler that you can use on the phone such as [compilr](http://compilr.com/)

**Edit:**

There is now a native C# REPL (Read/Eval/Print Loop) environment for Android: [Introducing C# To Go: a C# Compiler for Android](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/07/introducing-c-to-go-a-c-compiler-for-android/)

Comment: the online compiler thing is a good idea, however wht if i dont have wifi access at that time its better to have a editor on the phone itself if possible so is there any droid or nokia phone runninh maemo to have a c# editor i need a phones model along with the software name